# Sorting Algorithm Existence

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have written an algorithm for sorting that I thought of, and I'm not sure if it exists.  Basically, it runs through each index of an array and if the value of index n > the value of the index n+1, they get swapped.  My java code is below.

Here is the example of it running on an array of length 4.

```
(Given) [3,2,7,5]
(Step 1 [first loop]) [2,3,7,5]
(Step 1 [second iteration]) [2,3,7,5] (3<7, so no change)
(Step 1 [third iteration]) [2,3,5,7]
Sorted array detected, stopped.
```

This is my Java.

```
  public static int length = 10;
public static int[] data = new int[10];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    data[0] = 1;
    data[1] = 10;
    data[2] = 5;
    data[3] = 11;
    data[4] = 9;
    data[5] = 2;
    data[6] = 7;
    data[7] = 9;
    data[8] = 8;
    data[9] = 10;
    printstar();
    System.out.println();
    while(inOrder()){
        exchange();
        printstar();
    }



}

public static void exchange(){
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<length-1;i++){
        if(data[i] > data[i+1]){
            temp = data[i+1];
            data[i+1] = data[i];
            data[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

public static boolean inOrder(){
    for(int i = 0; i<length-1;i++){
        if(data[i] > data[i+1]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void printstar(){
    for (int i =0; i < length; i++){
        System.out.print(data[i]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

To clarify, `printstar()` prints the array.  `inOrder()` returns true if the array is not in order.  Returns false if it is in order.  `exchange()` changes the values.

**In summary, has a swapping algorithm like this been used before?**

Comment: Hi! Welcome to CS.SE. Unfortunately, I can't tell what your question is. If you just want to announce or draw attention to your algorithm, this isn't the place for it (creating your own blog would make more sense).  See our [help/dont-ask].  Also, coding questions and programming questions are off-topic here; our focus is on algorithms and concepts, not code.  Source code should be replaced with ideas, pseudo code and arguments of correctness. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/390/).

Comment: @D.W.  I am completely not trying to draw attention to my algorithm.  I am trying to know if something like this has been used before.  This algorithm is very basic and I want to know if it has been implemented before by people.

Comment: OK, sounds good.  I encourage you to edit your question to (a) state the question very clearly, (b) remove source code and replace it with pseudocode and concepts -- as mentioned in my previous comment.  If the question is clarified it can be considered for re-opening.

Comment: @intboolstring have you had a look at Bubblesort?

Comment: Ahh.  I think I wrote a bubble sort program without knowing